# How can make the user save his tasks?

Tags: html, css

How can I make the user able to save his tasks in my to do list website and when I write something in the text box I can't see it until I hit add a task can anyone explain why this problem happened in my website

```html
      <body>
               
         <div id="c"></div>
        <div id="newtasks">
        <input type="text" id="textInput" placeholder="Enter task" />   
      <button id="addTask">Add task</button><br />
      <div id="main">
     </div>
     <div id="tasks"></div>
     </div>

     <script>
      const main = document.querySelector("#main");
    const inputText = document.querySelector("#textInput");
     const taskBtn = document.querySelector("#addTask");

     function addTask(taskData) {
      const task = document.createTextNode(taskData);
      main.appendChild(task);
        main.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
         }
     taskBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
       if (inputText.value == "") {
        alert("please enter task!!");
      } else {
        addTask(inputText.value);
        inputText.value = "";
     }
      });

     </script>

     </body>
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wdcw.png
```

Comment: You can add your code directly within your answer instead of just having a picture. That way people trying to help you can copy and test your code :) Here’s a webpage showing you how: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: what do you mean you can't see it? do you have CSS code? maybe you set the text color to the same color as the background because I can see before and after pressing the add button.

Answer (score -1):

Your code needs the button to be pressed to add an item to the list, if it was adding things sooner, the list would be showing a letter by letter basis wouldn't it?

Can you elaborate on the desired result?

```js
const main = document.querySelector("#main");
const inputText = document.querySelector("#textInput");
const taskBtn = document.querySelector("#addTask");

function addTask(taskData) {
  const task = document.createTextNode(taskData);
  main.appendChild(task);
  main.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
taskBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (inputText.value == "") {
    alert("please enter task!!");
  } else {
    addTask(inputText.value);
    inputText.value = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="Go from idea to action in seconds with to-do list">[enter image description 
here][1]
  <title> list to do</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="c.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="c"></div>
  <div id="newtasks">
    <input type="text" id="textInput" placeholder="Enter task" />   
    <button id="addTask">Add task</button><br />
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="tasks"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wdcw.png
```